# JBoss server startup issues

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I downloaded JBoss 7.0.2 Final (zip format) from the below link:

http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/

I am not sure how to configure it for my newly downloaded Eclipse Juno.

What I did was:

1) Copied the extracted zip contents in my C:\Program files

2) In Eclipse IDE, add=>server=>JBoss AS 7.0=> finish.

Then I tried starting the server and got this exception:

**EDIT**

```
13:57:53,217 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.0.2.GA
13:57:54,106 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.1.GA
13:57:54,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final "Arc" starting
13:57:54,201 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service     jboss.as: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create a directory at C:\Program Files\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\standalone\data\content
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.repository.impl.ContentRepositoryImpl.<init>(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:77)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.repository.impl.ContentRepositoryImpl.addService(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:60)
at org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService.start(ApplicationServerService.java:118) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
... 3 more

13:57:54,201 ERROR [stderr] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed

13:57:54,201 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)

13:57:54,201 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)

13:57:54,201 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:106)

13:57:54,201 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

13:57:54,201 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:272)

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:313)

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr] Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.as: Failed to start service

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr]     at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1780)

13:57:54,217 ERROR [stderr]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know how to configure JBoss in Eclipse IDE in simple steps...am really confused when tried to dig into different links :(

Regards,

Comment: To avoid issues like that I use JBoss Studio, wich support JBoss AS better than common eclipse versions.

Comment: @Bhesh I have the two files in the folder as per ur suggestn...but now I am getting another exception. I have updated the exception in the aove post. Please let me know about the resolution.

Comment: Could be a matter of permissions on the installation folder, or an Eclipse wrong configuration parameter when adding the server, are you sure to have properly add the server specifying correct folders?

Comment: @remigio yes it seems that I have done it properly as i mentioned in my first post what exactly I did. Apart from that, what else shall I need to do? Do I need to add some entried in my system classpath? Please let me know about ur concerns so that i can cross-check the same.

Comment: @user182944 Seems that the user who starts the JBoss process has no permission to read/write the JBoss installation folder, try to give access to everyone or run Jboss as administrator

Comment: its not a permission issue...i am the admin.

Comment: Windows 7?? Have you tried starting eclipse as administrator ? Rightclick eclipse and select run as admin ?

Comment: Even if you are admin, but you are trying to create a folder/file at a protected location. "program files" , if you normally also create a folder there. It will ask for permission. Close eclipse, right click eclipse.exe and select run as admin. The you should be able to pass through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c:\Program Files\` is one of the protected folders on win7

So, it gives a warning when you try to create any folder/file there(even if you are admin), and when some program, in your case jboss,on top of eclipse tries to modify these areas, access is denied

suggestion:

1. Either move your jboss root to c:\ or better to some other drive
2. close eclipse, right click eclipse.exe and select run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run the eclipse.exe as admin, the server got started. But at the end in the console, i got this message: `20:04:15,051 WARN  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (pool-2-thread-2) JBAS012100: Got error closing channel JBREM00206: Channel is not open` Any specific reasons for this? Moreover, how to remove this?

Comment: @user182944 : not very sure, but looks like an instance of jboss is in pool, restart the system and try. It should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to the space in the ´C:\Program Files \´ path, try to install JBoss in the root folder and consequently change server configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: what you meant by the term `install JBoss` ? Is it extract the zip content and placing the content or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, extract it in the root folder C:\ instead of C:\Program Files\.